# Advice on a model or approach to layered dataset

Tags: regression, machine-learning, model

I am attempting to develop a model to estimate the number of people in a space based on the Wi-Fi Traffic.

At present, I have a dataset (in xml) which is structured like the following:

```
-- Scan 1 (has a parameter - timeout)
---- Device 1 
------ Manufacturer
------ Signal Strength
---- Device 2
------Manufacturer
------ Signal Strength
...
---- Device N
------ Manufacturer
------ Signal Strength
...
-- Scan 2
---- Device 1
...
```

Timeout is defined as: *The number of seconds since a device was last active before it is forgotten*. Example, if timeout = 10s, if a device was last seen 12s ago, it isn't included.

Each scan has a person count associated with it.

I was looking at how best to model this data. I looked at a very simple linear regression however this is awful.

Can anyone point me perhaps to an algorithm, method, book or toolkit which may help?

Thanks so much.

Comment: How frequent are the scans? Do you know if a given device that is detected in a given scan is the same as one of the devices that were detected in the previous scan?

Comment: The frequency of a scan is constant, and I don't hypothesize that the frequency of scan would make a difference.

Comment: The timeout is what is used to remember what devices have already been detected. All devices have a unique address which i can use to identify if I have detected them before.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem like a machine learning problem.  If the time between scans is less than the timeout period then you can simply keep track of how many devices there are in the space and know for sure.  If not, then you can use the examples and come up with a heuristic based on the parameters you have (number of known devices) and derivative parameters (e.g. average time left in timeout periods) to estimate the number of devices in the space.  I would play around with the data in a spreadsheet to find a good set of parameters and derivatives and only then decide how to solve this.  I suspect that machine learning may not be necessary and that you can come up with a simple heuristic to predict the number of devices.  For example, you may find that there are between 10% and 30% more devices present then the number of devices you are connected to and that the % greater is correlated with the average period.  In this case a simple heuristic like this may be accurate enough:
$$numDevices = numDetected * ( 1 + (maxPeriod/avgPeriod)*0.30)\,$$